# ACL vs Throughput

Tags: networking, acl, throughput

Can anyone provide me some information on whats the effect of Access Control List (ACL) on Throughput. For example, if the number of ACL entries increases from 10 to 1000, how much the throughput would change.
Thanks 
Oliver

Comment: An ACL `deny` rule would completely block throughput.

Comment: Does it mean that it adds more time delay to throughput? If you could kindly give some example, to clear my problem. Thanks.

Comment: That means that the throughput would be `0`. A deny rule would deny all traffic matching the rule.

Comment: say for example. I'm running a test, 10 ACL rules are there and 8 of them are deny while the rest is accept. 4 hosts are connected to the switch, I'm trying to log overall throughput for this scenario. Same scenario for 100 ACL rules with 80 deny and 20 permit rules , what will be the throughput in this case.

Comment: It is really vendor-dependent. For example, if this is done in software, e.g. Linux, it could add latency, but for a hardware ACL, e.g. Cisco, it is probably at wire-speed.

Comment: I'm not looking for any specific value. I just wanted to know in which case throughput would be higher? Linux one is my preferable environment .

Comment: Unfortunately, Linux does in software what may network devices do in hardware, so if is often (much) slower than a dedicated hardware device. If you want wire speed, you need a dedicated router, switch, etc.

Comment: Whats the case where throughput without ACL and with ACL, Which one is higher, with ACL or without ?